# Probability, rolling a dice or a pair considering the equation $x+2y\leq 2$

Tags: probability

Consider the square with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,2)$, $(2,0)$ and $(2,2)$. Five points are independently and randomly chosen from the square. If a point $(x,y)$ satisfies $x + 2y \leq  2$, then a pair of dice is rolled. Otherwise, a single die is rolled. Let $N$ be the total number of dice rolled. For $5\leq n \leq 10$, the probability that $N = n$ is?

Comment: Instead of rolling $n$ dice, you might as well eat $n$ red herrings, I suppose ...

Comment: your geometric prob. will be $p$ for Bernoulli trials, when you choose five points $P_n(k)=C_{n}^{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}$

Comment: $N-5$ is binomially distributed

Answer (score 2):

Area of the region where if the point happens to fall under the condition $x+2y<=2$ is $\frac{1}{2}1*2 = 1$.  The area of the square is 4.

Thus the probability that two dices would be rolled when the point fall in the above region is $\frac{1}{4}$.  Else $\frac{3}{4}$

What you will find out is

$P(N = 5) = {5\choose0} (\frac{3}{4})^5$

$P(N = 6) = {5\choose1} (\frac{3}{4})^4(\frac{1}{4})$

$P(N = 7) = {5\choose2} (\frac{3}{4})^3(\frac{1}{4})^2$

$P(N = 8) = {5\choose3} (\frac{3}{4})^2(\frac{1}{4})^3$

$P(N = 9) = {5\choose4} (\frac{3}{4})(\frac{1}{4})^4$

$P(N = 10) = {5\choose5}(\frac{1}{4})^5$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. The square $Q=[0,2]\times [0,2]$ is divided into two regions by the line $x+2y=2$. Then the probability that a random point $(x,y)$ is in the triangle $T$ under the line is equal to the ratio of $p=|T|/|Q|$ where $|A|$ denotes the area of the region $A$. Let $q=1-p$.

Note that to get $N=5$ you have always to roll a single die and get $1$ for each roll: $p(N=5)=\frac{q^5}{6^5}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is it possible that you misinterpreted the question? $N$ is merely the number of dice rolled, not the sum of the values of the considered dice.